# Firebase read and write by user

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm new to app development I want to make the user read and write his own data from fire base real time database and every user has his own data .

And this are the rules:

```
 {
  "rules": {
    ".read":true,
      ".write":true

  }
}
```

And here is a pic show what every single user have:

[image: every single user should have his won]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question exactly? What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: i want  everyone who uses the application reads and writes its own data

Comment: What you have posted does exactly what you required to do. Please elaborate your need.

Comment: i need get user id and by sing in Anonymous and use read and write his own data , i want to get database references by user id and child of this id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate your data into sections based on the user's UID.

So your data would need to be more like:

```
userId
   DONE_LIST
      ...
   TO_DO_LIST
      ...
   LESSONS
      ...
```

And then your rules can be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$uid": {
      ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
      ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
    }
  }
}
```

For more details on Firebase rules, please see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/#section-authorization.